# What are the risks of using Steam Gift Trades?

Tags: steam

I got an offer from a stranger to trade a CS:GO weapon skin for a game (Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare).

What are the risks with this trade? Can he request his game back? Could this game be unavailable in my country (Austria)?

Moreover, what are the possibilities for a good and safe trade of items and/or games?

Comment: Not a dupe but this is definitely relevant here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66579/what-are-the-dangers-of-accepting-gifts-from-unknown-accounts-on-steam?rq=1

Comment: No but he can do a chargeback on his credit card and steam takes the game from you. Don't trade with people you don't know.

Comment: @Noneofyourbusiness that is not true.

Comment: @Sickest That is true and entirely possible. Happens every day.

Comment: @Sickest Way to jeopardize your account. Go ahead if you want to, I don't care. But don't make others use unsafe methods. There is plenty of evidence how people got banned from their accounts for trading with the wrong people.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trading for quote a long time, and I tell you this, The steam trading world is FULL of scammers. So always be skeptical of anything that doesn't seem right or common to you.

1. Never do trades involving paypal for items as payment.
2. Never accept game codes, or steam wallet codes as payment
3. Checking a person's profile for clues if they are trustworthy is pointless.
4. There is a [website](http://www.steamrep.com) which you can see if a person has previous offenses to any trades they have made in the past and were already reported.

Once you make a trade it's final according to steam. But if the item you got was purchased in a fraudulent manner which resulted in them removing that item or game from your account specifically. Steam will take action to rectify the problem on your end because it was not your fault. It's happened to me before.

As long as they actually placed the game in your trade window and you can see physically see it. You should be ok to trade it.

Answer (score -1):

There are always risks when trading.

One common problems I have been seeing recently is when the game gift is bought fraudulently and then traded. When Steam detect the fraud they revoke the game gift and remove it from your library/inventory, regardless of whose inventory it is in or if they had installed it.