# Is redeeming game codes on Steam dangerous?

Tags: steam

I got a PM from a guy on Steam asking personal information. I told him no. He then sent me some code and asked me to "**redeem**"" the game (represented by the code?).

Is it potentially dangerous if I redeem that code? Will it reveal my personal information?

Comment: Please comment why you are downvoting.

Comment: This has less to do with gaming, and more with information security.

Comment: So the better option would be to flag it for a move right

Comment: You could do that. We're experts about Steam, so there may be a place for it here, but information security definitely isn't in our skillset. If you want to know how Steam works, that we can help with. If you want to know how to keep your Steam info secure, that definitely isn't, beyond the obvious skeptical computing practice.

Comment: I feel like this is more about Steam than general information security. I'm not seeing it as "How do I keep my information safe online?" but more "What happens when I redeem a Steam code, and why would this scammer want me to do so?"

Comment: @SaintWacko Exactly. I am asking specifically about the redeem process. And there are no similar questions. So I dont understand the downvotes really.

Comment: @Saintwacko Which is information security. The topic is broader than just keeping your info secure, I think.

Comment: Just throwing my two cents into the ring but I am not sure this would be useful on Information Security since that exchange is a lot more technical than the question asked and is more about the inner works of security.

Comment: @Ramirez77 it's not exactly useful here, either. It really boils down to "Why shouldn't I take the bait from an obvious scammer? What could go wrong?"

Comment: @Vemonus that is true too, I mean this question could be spun as a question about is redeeming codes on steam in general dangerous since the title kind of hints at that question to begin with. But hey it's not really my call to say if it is proper or not.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66579/what-are-the-dangers-of-accepting-gifts-from-unknown-accounts-on-steam).

Comment: @Vemonus I was looking for that, I knew I saw something like this before.

Answer (score 5):

The redeem system can not really be exploited as far as I know. However, the fact that this individual wanted to have personal information gives a big red flag of the nature of the steam code. There are some scenarios I can think of:

- The key is stolen. The scammer tries to gain your trust this way. I am not a lawyer, but I believe buying or using stolen goods is usually forbidden by law.
- The scammer somehow got malicious code in the steam shop, and gifts you that game/software. They try to get your information that way.
- They are trying to con Steam customer support. They create known knowledge by letting you redeem that key, then they can "tell" customer support the otherwise unknown key to try to proof they are the legitimate owner of the account.
- They want to create a "paper trail" to unsuspecting people to decrease the risk of them getting in trouble and to throw people investigating off.

In either case, it is not worth the trouble. Don't accept the key. Report this particular user for scamming via their profile.

Comment: I agree, he should report the user and steam code ASAP. All your options are very sound.

Answer (score 4):

I would not trust that guy at all or redeem his code he is trying to pass off to you. But for the most part as long as you get a steam code from a reputable source (for example, Humble Store, GMG, etc) places like that the codes are perfectly safe. But I would not have any other contact with the person that PMed you. They are clearly trying to scam you.